# Вопрос по js - selecet

Tags: javascript, html

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при выборе в селекте был полный список - `option`. Но когда какой-то `option` выбран - убирать все остальные варианты? Желательно в `juqery`.

**Первый выбор**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Когда что-то выбрали:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прошу прощения. Не подскажите название шрифта в выпадающем списке и кнопочки  ДОБАВИТЬ ПОКУПАТЕЛЯ? Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: 'Open Sans',sans-serif -  в списке , geometriabold - добавить

Comment: Не кажется ли Вам такая стратегия интерфейса слегка... ужасной? Очепятался курсором и только перезагрузка страницы и новое заполнение.

Comment: дизайн заказчика) там еще крестик будет, чтобы сбросить

Answer (score 2):

Используем фильтр `:not(селектор)` - удаляет все, кроме указанных селекторов

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  $('#select').change(function () {
    $('#select option:not(#select option:selected)').remove();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
    <option value="s1">s1</option>
    <option value="s2">s2</option>
    <option value="s3">s3</option>
</select>
```